# Creating a dataset (data frame,df) in R consisting of all possible combinations of 10 different variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, combn

Thanks in advance for any advice. As part of a study, I need to:

**Part 1:**

I need to create a .csv dataset (or r data frame?) that produces all possible combinations of 10 different variables. Each of the 10 variables has either 2 (i.e., binary 0,1) or 4 levels. *I think this should be possible easily in both excel and r, but r would be preferable.* They are provided in the table below:[image]

For example, the first set of combinations would keep "druga_LIFE" at 0.5 and then would cycle through all combinations of the other variables, then it would follow by fixing "druga_LIFE" at 1 and cycling through all other combinations of variables. Eventually, it would move on to fix "druga.NEED" at 0 changing other variables, then at 1 and so on.

The dataset should be a full set of combinations with no repeat combinations.

I understand there is a large number of possible combinations - this is as expected, but I don't think this should be too difficult to compute.

**Part 2:**

I then need to go through this dataset, selecting only the possible combinations where:

1. "druga.LIFE" is the same as "drugb.LIFE"

AND

2)"druga.NEED" is the same as  "drugb.NEED"

I think this should be simple with the dplyr package in R.

I have created the df in r, but do not know how to begin with cycling through to produce all possible combinations.

```
#DATASET OF ALL POSSIBLE CHOICE SETS#

#Creating the Vectors of choices

DrugA_LIFE <- c(0.5, 1, 2,5)
DrugA_NEED <- c(0,1)
DrugA_CERT <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6)
DrugA_RISK <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6)
DrugA_WAIT <- c(0, 0.5, 1, 2)

DrugB_LIFE <- c(0.5, 1, 2,5)
DrugB_NEED <- c(0,1)
DrugB_CERT <- c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6)
DrugB_RISK <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6)
DrugB_WAIT <- c(0, 0.5, 1, 2)

#Create data frame

df <- data.frame(DrugA_LIFE, DrugA_NEED, DrugA_CERT, DrugA_RISK, DrugA_WAIT, DrugB_LIFE,      DrugB_NEED, DrugB_CERT, DrugB_RISK, DrugB_WAIT)
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189. I don't know how the backslashes were inserted into your code, but they make it harder for others to try to use your code. I'll fix it here, please refrain from adding them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. All possible combinations? `expand.grid` or `tidyr::expand_big`. We can apply either function to an already-made frame using `do.call`.
2. Unique? Use R's `unique` or `dplyr::distinct`.
3. Filtering? Use ... `dplyr::filter` (or base R `subset`).

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # expand_grid
do.call(tidyr::expand_grid, df) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  filter(DrugA_LIFE == DrugB_LIFE, DrugA_NEED == DrugB_NEED)
# # A tibble: 32,768 × 10
#    DrugA_LIFE DrugA_NEED DrugA_CERT DrugA_RISK DrugA_WAIT DrugB_LIFE DrugB_NEED DrugB_CERT DrugB_RISK DrugB_WAIT
#         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#  1        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.1        0  
#  2        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.1        0.5
#  3        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.1        1  
#  4        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.1        2  
#  5        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.2        0  
#  6        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.2        0.5
#  7        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.2        1  
#  8        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.2        2  
#  9        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.4        0  
# 10        0.5          0          0        0.1          0        0.5          0          0        0.4        0.5
# # … with 32,758 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(DrugA_LIFE = c(0.5, 1, 2, 5), DrugA_NEED = c(0, 1, 0, 1), DrugA_CERT = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6), DrugA_RISK = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6), DrugA_WAIT = c(0, 0.5, 1, 2), DrugB_LIFE = c(0.5, 1, 2, 5), DrugB_NEED = c(0, 1, 0, 1), DrugB_CERT = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6), DrugB_RISK = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6), DrugB_WAIT = c(0, 0.5, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```